# Can't access array within hash (Google People API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-contacts-api, google-api-ruby-client, google-people-api

I'm using the [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/) to populate a user's contacts in my Rails 5 app, but I don't think this issue is specific to this particular API.

Bottom line, I'm able to successfully call the API and get a JSON response with all my Google contacts.

Here is the call I'm making to the API in one of my controller actions:

```
@response = HTTParty.get('https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?requestMask.includeField=person.names%2Cperson.emailAddresses%2Cperson.phoneNumbers&access_token=' + @token,
:headers =>{'Content-Type' => 'application/json'} )
```

Next, in the same controller file, I parse the JSON response:

```
@parsed_response = JSON.parse(@response.body)
```

This provides an output that looks like the following (I've simplified it for sharing):

```
{"connections"=>
  [{
    "resourceName"=>"people/c6173361945899061031", "etag"=>"FB4d1LieX4k=",                                  
     "names"=>[{"metadata"=>{"primary"=>true, "source"=>{"type"=>"CONTACT", "id"=>"55ac2f1281953f27"}}, "displayName"=>"John Smith", "familyName"=>"Smith", "givenName"=>"John", "displayNameLastFirst"=>"Smith, John"}],
     "phoneNumbers"=>[{"metadata"=>{"primary"=>true, "source"=>{"type"=>"CONTACT", "id"=>"55ac2f1281953f27"}}, "value"=>"+18083416177", "canonicalForm"=>"+18083416177", "type"=>"mobile", "formattedType"=>"Mobile"}]
  }],
"nextPageToken"=>"CGQQm7Ohg", "nextSyncToken"=>"CPvkoIP1KhIBMRiGE"}
```

The parsed JSON above contains information for one of my contacts, but in the actual file the "connections" array contains a hash for each contact. What I'm trying to do is iterate through the entire "connections" array to display a list of all my contacts' names. My completed controller actions looks like this:

*controller.rb*

```
@response = HTTParty.get('https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?requestMask.includeField=person.names%2Cperson.emailAddresses%2Cperson.phoneNumbers&access_token=' + @token,
:headers =>{'Content-Type' => 'application/json'} )

@parsed_response = JSON.parse(@response.body)

@google_contacts = @parsed_response['connections']
```

This now creates an array (@google_contacts) of hashes for each of my contacts. Then, within my view I try iterating over that hash to pull out the 'displayName' field for each contact:

*view.html.erb*

```
<% @google_contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <%= contact['names'][0]['displayName'] %>
<% end %>
```

What results; however, is the lovely **undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass** error message. When I remove **[0]['displayName']**, the view displays the full contents of 'names' array for each contact (for example):

```
[{"metadata"=>{"primary"=>true, "source"=>{"type"=>"CONTACT", "id"=>"55ac2f1281953f27"}}, "displayName"=>"John Smith", "familyName"=>"Smith", "givenName"=>"John", "displayNameLastFirst"=>"Smith, John"}]
```

When I try just extracting the first contact in the array, the following works without any issues:

```
<% @google_contacts[0,1].each do |contact| %>
  <%= contact['names'][0]['displayName'] %>
<% end %>
```

I just cannot successfully extract the contact's displayName for multiple contacts within the array, without getting the error thrown at me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest running this in your console to check if this returns anything `@google_contacts.select { |contact| contact['names'][0].blank? }`

Comment: @LarsonB thanks for your response. I tried running your suggestion (not in the console, but created a new variable in my same controller) and the statement came back as nil. Does that suggest something to you?

Comment: If that statement returned nil, then there is no possibility of this particular exception happening. I am thinking you might not have posted the exact code here.